# "simple" dev/prod build to add https for static+react+express

Tags: html, node.js, express, webpack, development-environment

What's the simplest way to "build" a static web page and Node backend such that the Node server runs in HTTPS in dev mode (but not production) and the static web page can point to `https://localhost/foo` in dev, but just `/foo` in production?

## Long Story

This is probably a mess, and probably not The Right Way to do things, but this is my first time using React for anything other than an SPA, so I've never had to deal with Webpack/Babel (or any other build tools) before.

I have a static landing page, which has a couple of React components in it (i.e., it's not a SPA where it's all React, it's just loading React components to a few `root`s). One of them is for handling Stripe payments. There's also a simple back-end Node server to handle the Stripe payment-intent creation and web hooks that get registered with Stripe.

To simplify development, I've put this all in one repository, that looks like this:

```
repo/app.js
     devserver.js
     index.html
     package.json
     client/package.json
            webpack.config.js
            src/<react stuff>
     server/package.json
           /index.js
           /<other node stuff>
     public/<webpack output>
```

The `index.html` is the static page. The top-level `app.js`, `devserver.js`, and `package.json` really only exist for development, so I can load the static web page on localhost and watch for source changes on both the React and Node sides.

`repo/package.json`:

```
{
  "name": "landing-page",
  "version": "0.99.2",
  "description": "Static HTML for landing page",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "npm-run-all build:dev:client -p start:* watch:client",
    "start:devserver": "nodemon devserver.js",
    "start:server": "cd server && npm start",
    "watch:client": "cd client && npm start",
    "build:dev:client": "cd client && npm run build:dev",
    ...
```

So, if I `npm start`, it

1. builds the React stuff —

`repo/client/package.json`:

```
{
  "name": "landing-page-react",
  "version": "0.99.2",
  "description": "React components for landing page",
  "private": true,
  "main": "index.js",
  "homepage": ".",
  "scripts": {
    "build:dev": "webpack --config ./webpack.config.js --mode development",
    "start": "webpack --watch --config ./webpack.config.js --mode development",
    ...
```

and `repo/client/webpack.config.js`:

```
const path = require('path');
const Dotenv = require('dotenv-webpack');

module.exports = (env, argv) => {
  console.log('Webpack mode: ', argv.mode);

  const config = {
    entry: path.resolve(__dirname, './src/index.js'),
    plugins: [
      new Dotenv()
    ],
    module: {
      rules: [
        {
          test: /\.(js)$/,
          exclude: /node_modules/,
          use: ['babel-loader']
        }
      ]
    },
    resolve: {
      extensions: ['*', '.js', '.jsx']
    },
    output: {
      path: path.resolve(__dirname, '../public'),
      filename: 'bundle.js',
    },
    devServer: {
      contentBase: path.resolve(__dirname, '../public'),
    },
    mode: argv.mode
  }

  return config;
};
```

putting the output back up in `repo/public` whence it's included in `index.html`.

2. Launches the Node server —

`repo/server/package.json`:

```
{
  "name": "landing-page-node-module",
  "version": "0.99.2",
  "description": "Process stripe payments for landing page",
  "private": true,
  "main": "index.js",
  "type": "module",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "NODE_OPTIONS='--experimental-specifier-resolution=node --trace-warnings' nodemon index.js",
```

and the "dev" server, so I can actually see/use the `index.html` page:

`repo/devserver.js`:

```
const http = require('http');
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3000;

const appServer = require('./app');
const httpServer = http.createServer(appServer);

httpServer.listen(PORT);
console.log(`Listening on port ${PORT}...`);
```

`repo/app.js`:

```
const path = require('path');
const express = require('express');

const app = express();
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname)));
app.use('/', express.static('index.html'));

module.exports = app;
```

This all already seems a little preposterously complex, but, it works. If I navigate to `localhost:3000` it loads my `index.html`, which pulls in the React transpiled scripts from `repo/public`; that frontend communicates fine with the Node server running on `localhost:9292`; and if I make anyone changes to either the server side or the client side, it all gets "watched" and reloaded. So, so far so good.

Now the problem. I want to add logging both in the static web page and the React components, such that those logs go to the Node server.

In the `index.html` I've added

```
      <script>
          function sendToLog(data) {
              const body = JSON.stringify(data);

              // Use `navigator.sendBeacon()` if available, falling back to `fetch()`.
              (navigator.sendBeacon && navigator.sendBeacon('/api/log', body)) ||
                  fetch('/api/log', {body, method: 'POST', kee  palive: true});
          }
      </script>
```

There are two problems with this. First, `'/api/log'` would work fine in production, but doesn't in dev, because it needs to go to a different port. So I need to "build" the static `index.html` such that it's `'/api/log'` for production, but `'localhost:9292/api/log'` in dev. Second, I need the node server to run over `https` in dev, because `sendBeacon` requires that. Third, I'm hoping the React code will be able to rely on that `sendToLog` function because it's available in the parent page, but am prepared for the possibility that I may need to do some custom building of the React components as well.

In production, this is all behind a Apache, which is in turn behind a CDN. The CDN forces `https` and when the requests hit Apache, it just proxies any `/api` URLs to the node server on localhost over `http`, so ... everything Just Works. But there is no `https` (nor Apache) in my dev environment.

I started down a path of putting a bunch of `if ('production' !== process.env.NODE_ENV` code in the server to use a local CA and certs, but it occurs to me that this is not the right thing to do. It feels like the server should be built using the secure config when in dev, and not when in prod (because it's secured through other means, and why add the overhead). And, ideally, I'd like to use the same tool to build the static html file.

Given where I am, what's the simplest way to do this? Is this something that can reasonably/easily be done with Webpack and babel? Or do I need to add something else (I have no idea what, Gulp?) to my build process? And either way, any pointers on where to start configuring this?

Answer (score 0):

Long term, this entire thing will probably have to be redone (maybe as NextJS), and somewhere between where I am now and then, there are probably better ways to do this with WebPack and [WebpackHtmlPlugin](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/html-webpack-plugin/), but the simple way I ended up going was to use [EJS](https://ejs.co) from the command line in `package.json` to build the `index.html`:

`npm i ejs --save-dev`

`package.json`:

```
{
  "name": "seminar-landing-page",
  "version": "0.99.2",
  "description": "Static HTML for landing page",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    ...
    "build:dev:views": "ejs views/index.ejs -f views/config/index.dev.json -o ./index.html",
  },
```

Then the code snippet from `index.html` becomes in `repo/views/index.ejs`:

```
  <script>
      function sendToLog(data) {
          const body = JSON.stringify(data);

          // Use `navigator.sendBeacon()` if available, falling back to `fetch()`.
          (navigator.sendBeacon && navigator.sendBeacon('<%- api_server _%>/api/log', body)) ||
              fetch('<%- api_server _%>/api/log', {body, method: 'POST', keepalive: true});
      }
  </script>
```

and I have separate prod and dev config.json files, `repo/views/config/index.dev.json`:

```
{
    "api_server": "https://localhost:9292"
}
```

`repo/views/config/index.prod.json`:

```
{
    "api_server": ""
}
```

On the server side, I did end up going with an `if`, but I only ended up having to do it in one place:

```
import { readFileSync } from 'fs';
const PROD = ('production' === process.env.NODE_ENV);
if (PROD) {
  app.listen(PORT, () => logger.debug(`LISTENING AT PORT ${PORT}`));
} else {
  let https;
  try {
    https = await import('node:https');
  } catch (err) {
    logger.error('HTTPS support is required in dev and disabled in node');
    process.exit(1);
  }

    const key = readFileSync('./config/cert.key');
    const cert = readFileSync('./config/cert.crt');

    const server = https.createServer({ key: key, cert: cert }, app);

    server.listen(PORT, () => logger.debug(`LISTENING HTTPS AT PORT ${PORT}`));
}
```